# What is the intuition behind having high Accuracy but bad Adjusted Rand Index?

Tags: classification, clustering, model-evaluation, metric

I'm working on a problem, in which the learning algorithm consistently produces high accuracy on the different samples it is tested on, but generally has a rather unsatisfactory adjusted Rand index (that is, negative or close to 0).

However, I'm unable to find a valid explanation to this. That is, the model is predicting with high accuracy, but it is still worse than random assignment in general? I doesn't seem to add up to me.

I apologise for not being able to provide more detail on what I'm working on, but I hope this would be enough to open a discussion around this topic.

Answer (score 0):

The adjusted Rand Index is a harsh measure, since every clustering error is counted many times, once for each other object that the erroneously classified object is paired with. It can be a useful training objective but it's not the one I would report to the client! KL divergence is a reasonable metric.

However, your question makes me wonder: are you making a classifier or a clusterer? If a classifier, then accuracy is a useful metric (but you must be careful if the sets are unbalanced - few people currently have cancer, so a test that says everyone is healthy is very accurate but also useless). But then the Rand Index would not tell you much.

If it is a clusterer then the Rand Index is useful, but there is no such thing as accuracy. Accuracy is "the model assigns the right label" in a classifier. In a clustering problem, you are looking for clusters, but there is no natural label for each cluster.

Comment: Indeed the problem I'm working on in computer vision can be seen as a classification of pixels, but also a clustering of pixels; both of which may be valid perspectives to study the problem from. Thank you for your answer, it makes sense to me now. I will check the KL divergence too!